# Java Joda - Infinite iterations when trying to loop through date, month and year

Tags: java, sql, datetime, jodatime

I have to create tables for each day of every month between a specific date range (For eg. 2012-01-30 to 2013-04-30). I'm trying to do this using three for loops and DateTime isBefore method, however my loop runs infinitely (although the date, month and year are incremented as how its supposed to be). A snippet of the code that I wrote below,

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
DateTime startDate = dtf.parseDateTime(startDateTime);
DateTime endDate = dtf.parseDateTime(endDateTime);
try{

    for(DateTime y=startDate;y.isBefore(endDate);y=y.plusYears(1)) {
        for(DateTime month=startDate;startDate.isBefore(endDate);month=month.plusMonths(1)) {
           for(DateTime date=startDate;startDate.isBefore(endDate);date=date.plusDays(1)){
                String sqlStmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...
                ...
            }
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {

StackTraceElement stack = e.getStackTrace()[2];

  }
```

My tables are getting created as how I want them so there is no issue with the sqlstmt that I'm trying to execute, just that the loop doesn't terminate once it encounters the endDate. I'm new to Java so not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestions would be really helpful!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't this your issue ?

```
 for(DateTime month=startDate;startDate.isBefore(endDate);month=month.plusMonths(1)) {
```

You're incrementing `month`, but comparing the value of `startDate`, which doesn't change.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, but Joda should allow you to iterate across days, weeks, months etc. simply by adding a day (`plusDays(1)`) to an initial date.

Comment: Like you've mentioned, turns out I didn't need the for loop for year and month at all (rookie mistake!!!). So I removed them, and iterated my date loop with date.isBefore instead of startDate.isBefore and it works perfectly. Thanks very much!